# Why does `settowidth` not work inside `foreach`?

Tags: loops, lengths

I would expect the first two `a` to be `wide` apart on the first line..

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}
\foreach \i in {dum,iteration} {%
    \settowidth{\mylength}{wide}% this does not seem to work..
}
a\hspace{\mylength}a % .. because the length still looks zero.

\settowidth{\mylength}{wide} % but this does work..
a\hspace{\mylength}a % .. although it's the exact same line X(

\end{document}
```

[image]

But they are not. Why? How can I get `\settowidth` to work inside the loop?

Comment: `\settowidth` occurs within a group, hence the output. A possible workaround would be `\global\mylength=\mylength` after `\settowidth` but maybe there are smarter ways.

Comment: @campa not only your gut..... (it would break calc package, at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a guess as my crystal ball is in maintenance. `;-)`

You have a list of words and want to set `\mylength` to the largest width thereof.

Since every cycle in `\foreach` is performed inside a group, using it is hopeless, because `\mylength` would return to its previous value as soon as the group ends.

Here's a cycle that does the job.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\settolargestwidth}{mm}
 {% #1 = length to set, #2 = list of words
  \iagolito_settolargestwidth:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }

% A function still missing from expl3
\box_new:N \l__iagolito_dim_setto_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__iagolito_dim_setto:NNn
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__iagolito_dim_setto_box { #3 }
  \dim_set:Nn #1 { #2\l__iagolito_dim_setto_box }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \iagolito_dim_settowidth:Nn
 {
  \__iagolito_dim_setto:NNn #1 \box_wd:N { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \iagolito_dim_settoheight:Nn
 {
  \__iagolito_dim_setto:NNn #1 \box_ht:N { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \iagolito_dim_settodepth:Nn
 {
  \__iagolito_dim_setto:NNn #1 \box_dp:N { #2 }
 }
%%%

\dim_new:N \l__iagolito_tempa_dim
\dim_new:N \l__iagolito_tempb_dim
\seq_new:N \l__iagolito_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \iagolito_settolargestwidth:Nn
 {
  \dim_zero:N \l__iagolito_tempa_dim
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__iagolito_temp_seq { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__iagolito_temp_seq
   {
    \iagolito_dim_settowidth:Nn \l__iagolito_tempb_dim { ##1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__iagolito_tempa_dim
     {
      \dim_max:nn { \l__iagolito_tempa_dim } { \l__iagolito_tempb_dim }
     }
   }
  \dim_set:Nn #1 { \l__iagolito_tempa_dim }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength{\mylength}

\begin{document}

\settolargestwidth{\mylength}{a,bbb,cc}

xbbby

x\hspace{\mylength}y

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: *sigh*, I knew it was going to turn complicated, as always with LaTeX X) But you nailed it. And your guess was correct : I was looking for the max length indeed :) Thank you for your explanation. And `\ExplSyntaxOn` saves the day again!

Comment: This makes this post a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/278779) instance. Should we rename it or something?